# Can I rename "ArrayList<Integer>" for syntactic sugar purposes?

Tags: java, arraylist, syntactic-sugar

In my code, I have two very different uses for an ArrayList that I would like to separate: either using it as a coordinate, or as an array of 1D indexes. To that end, I tried doing this:

```
public abstract class Sugar
{
    public static class Indexes extends ArrayList<Integer> {}

    public static class Coord extends ArrayList<Integer> {}
}
```

This seemed to be working until I tried using non-default constructors, such that now the compiler is yelling at me when I try to do stuff like this:

```
public Integer getIndex(Integer ... inDims)
{
    return getIndex(new Sugar.Coord(Arrays.asList(inDims)));
}
```

Do I need to redefine all the constructors in the extended classes, or am I out of luck with this approach? Hopefully I'm missing something totally obvious; I've been trying to search for other people who have tried this but I couldn't figure out what kind of query Google/Stack Overflow would direct me to the right question.

Comment: I imagine you would need to define the constructors to call the base constructors, yes.  Also note that while this may save a few keystrokes here and there it makes the code a lot more difficult to support in the long run.  Typing keystrokes into the IDE isn't difficult, supporting unintuitive code is.

Comment: Alternatively, your types could use ArrayList as part of their private representation, rather than extending it.

Comment: I suggest using composition.  Say you decide that using an `int[]` is much more efficient han using an `List<Integer>`, it would be harder to change if you haven't hidden away how the ints are actually stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the constructors: yes, you would have to write them all. Fortunatly, most IDEs (Eclipse, netbeans, ...) enable automatic generation of constructors from super class, so you don't need to write them down mannualy.

**However**, I wouldn't use this sugar approach at all. If you need to differentiate between coordinates and indexes, I would do it with variable names or method names, not class type.

***However***, your approach have (at least) 1 advantage: safety. As it is now, you can't assign `Coords` to `Indexes` or vide versa, so there is lesser chance of wrong code by mistake.

Comment: "However, your approach have (at least) 1 advantage: safety. As it is now, you can't assign Coords to Indexes or vide versa, so there is lesser chance of wrong code by mistake."

This is what I was going for, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would have to implement all the constructors that you wanted your new type to expose.

And yes, it is reasonable and useful to implement your own types.

However, it would be worthwhile to consider whether you want your types to be ArrayLists, or whether you merely wish to use ArrayList as part of the implementation. A general principle is to ***prefer composition over inheritance***.

For example, for your Coord class, extending ArrayList allows arbitrarily many dimensions. If this isn't what you want, then encapsulating the representation gives you more control than extending.

```
public static class Coord {
    private List<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Coord( int x, int y, int z ) {
        coord.add( x );
        coord.add( y );
        coord.add( z );
    }

    // Other constructors and methods you want to expose.
}
```

Encapsulating the representation also gives you the ability to change it later. For example, you could change it to an `int[]` to reduce the memory footprint, without requiring changes to any clients of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point on extending if you are not overriding nor adding new features. All you are doing is simply creating inner classes that will be hardly used by anyone. You do not have the constructor you are trying to use since you created a subclass. If you want to go ahead with this design (which I do not recommend), you will need to override constructors that basically only call super.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. If you have class `A` with constructor that accepts argument and you want to define subclass `B` you should somehow call the super class's constructor:

```
class A {
    A(int i) {
    }

    A(String s) {
    }
}


class B extends A {
    B(int i) {
       super(i);
    }

    B(String s) {
       super(i);
    }
}
```

BTW do not have to call constructor that gets the same type. For example I can say:

```
B(String s) {
   super(s.length()); // call int constructor of supper class
}
```

(I used `s.length()` just for example).

*BUT*

You are definitely on the wrong way. It is not a syntactic sugar if you define subclass for each type of collection. It is...  I even do not know what. Instead you should *always* try to use interfaces when it is possible. For example indexes is just a list:

```
private List<Integer> indexes = ArrayList<>();
```

or even just a `Collection`

```
private Collection<Integer> indexes = ArrayList<>();
```

or even just a `Iterable`

```
private Iterable<Integer> indexes = ArrayList<>();
```

This makes your code better designed because you can always change the implementation (e.g. change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` or even to `Set` (for 2 last examples) or even to Cassandra `ResultSet` (for the last example) without changing code that operates with indexes.